# Proving ideals are equal using Nakayama’s Lemma

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

We have this problem in the course “Introduction to Commutative Algebra”:

> $\mathbb{k}$ is a field, and $\mathbb{k}[x,y]$ is the ring of polynomials of two variables.
>
> Given $p_3, q_3, r_3 \in (x,y)^3$, prove that $(x,y)^2 = (x^2 + p_3, xy + q_3, y^2 + r_3)$.

We were given this kind of problem as an example of applying [Nakayama's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma) but weren’t instructed on how to use it.
The other examples we saw were related to modules over local rings which is not the case in this problem.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: This is false. Take $p_3=q_3=r_3=-x^3$, then every polynomial in the ideal generated by the RHS vanishes at $(1,1)$, but $x^2$ (which is in the LHS) doesn’t.